# Help with select query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table with 2 columns:]

```
ID  Name
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
2   E
2   F
```

And I want write a query to have output like :

```
1  A  B   C  D
2  E  F
```

It's possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good article you can look at :

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/

Comment: Could you please post a summary of that article to avoid link rot?

Answer (score 2):

You want a Pivot, which is easy in excel, but requires (I believe) quite a bit of work in SQL Server, as it is hard to determine how many columns you need. You could dynamically construct the sql based on a max() aggregate, I suppose.

Start looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)